# Injecting oAuth 2.0 access token as parameter to service layer

Tags: dependency-injection, oauth-2.0, autofac, dotnetopenauth, asp.net-mvc-5

I stuck at somewhere in dependency injection and oAuth 2.0 tokens. I have a service layer underneath my asp.net mvc5 web application. My generic repository (entity framework 6) is injecting by Autofac to all my services. But now one of my service should contact with one of external REST Api. Which is that api requires oAuth2.0 authentication. So my service layer should receive access token via injecting parameter (autofac).

In that place actually i am having the issue. How can i inject oAuth2.0 access token to my services. And if token is not valid anymore where (which layer) should i refresh the token ?

Could you please share your opinion ? Thanks in advance.